# Fuse-type software decrypting NTFS

Tags: encryption, ntfs, fuse

I have a large file(70G) which, when decrypted, is an NTFS partition. For time saving i'd like to write software which can decrypt the file on the fly, and serve it as a file system for an user to modify. As far as i have understood, you provide FUSE with directories yourself, and therefore, i would have to manually parse and handle NTFS if i wanted to use FUSE.

What would be a nice and easy way to accomplish on-the-go decryption of an NTFS filesystem, with a custom crypto algorithm(looping long xor key), and serving it as a modifyable file system to a user? Is there something like this which i should be aware of?

Comment: Is the file already encrypted using the XOR method you described?

Comment: Yes, i want to decrypt it as needed for reading and writing, so i don't have to re-encrypt the entire file each time.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that the encryption method you have chosen is quite poor in terms of actual security, it is very easy to read from the file at any arbitrary position using modular arithmetic:

If your key was, say, `chocolate`, then you know that the position in your file mod the length of your key (9) would give the index in the key to begin XORing with.

For example, lets say you want to start decrypting from position 25 in your file.  We take `25 mod 9 = 7` and so we start XORing our key with our ciphertext at position 7 in the key (`techocolatecho...`).

Comment: Problem is that the file is an entire file system. I want to be able to treat the file as a mounted disk. So i can read and write as usual and offload the NTFS work to something else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why you'd want to limit that to NTFS, it just doesn't make sense to me. The most straightforward (and I'd even say simple) way would be to write virtual disk driver (see mass storage device), which would handle just several IRPs (IRP_MJ_CREATE/CLOSE, IRP_MJ_READ/WRITE, IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL should be enough for such device).

Then you'd have just another volume, where you'd handle reads and writes and the actual storage might be whatever you want. And please try use better encryption than XOR.

Comment: I don't control its contents, i just have to work with the file.

Comment: The original solution is a disk driver, but i would like to have it easily portable to other operating systems. Crypto was not my choice.

Comment: Yes, such virtual disk driver serves as a layer between encrypted file/remote file/whatever. I believe the same thing you can achieve with FUSE.